# submit data and it show Undefined offset: 3c I used forloop

Tags: php, laravel

When I am Try To use A For-loop in my controller in store function to submit a data

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tender = new TenderMaster;

    $tender->bid_name = $request->bid_name;
    $tender->bid_year = $request->bid_year;
    $tender->shipping_mode = $request->shipping_mode;
    $tender->start_date = $request->start_date;
    $tender->end_date = $request->end_date;
    $explodeval = explode(",",$request->origin_port);

    $tender->freight_forwarder = $request->freight_forwarder;
    $tender->save();

    for($i=0;$i<=count($explodeval);$i++){
        $tender->airPorts()->attach($explodeval[$i]);
    }

return back();
}
```

Comment: its not a same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple arrays start at index 0 and end at index count()-1

```
$my_array=['foo','bar','baz'];

// > 3
echo count($my_array)

// > 'foo'
echo $my_array[0]

// > 'baz'
echo $my_array[2]

// error
echo $my_array[3]
```

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($explodeval); $i++){
    $tender->airPorts()->attach($explodeval[$i]);
}
```

Your error is because you used the condition `$i <= count(...`, which means that if `count($array) == 3` you will get a loop that executes `0, 1, 2, 3`. That's 4 elements instead of 3.

You don't have 4 elements in the array, and you don't have an index `$array[3]`.

You can try reading up on php documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: thank you @Qonvex620 it's working and i accept this answr !